# Separating Means/Averages In Large Expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, probability-or-statistics

I have very large analytical expressions that are averaged "Mean[...]" and I would like to simpify as much as possible. The issue is that although Mathematica recognizes the commutative property:

```
Mean[a*b]-Mean[b*a]=0
```

Its does not recognize distributive property:

```
Mean[a+b]-Mean[a]-Mean[b] =/= 0
```

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to implement this distributive property? For example, have Mathematica recognize that:

```
Mean[a+b]-Mean[a]-Mean[b] = 0
```

Like I said I have expressions that are extremely long and would love to be able to just have Mathematica take the average and then Simplify[...] for me.

Comment: You could write your own rule:  `Mean[a - b] - Mean[a] + 
  Mean[b] //. {Mean[x_ + y_] -> Mean[x] + Mean[y], 
  Mean[-x_] -> -Mean[x]}`.  (The second rule is needed as there might be subtraction for some cases.)

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on Jim's comment:

```
Mean[a + b - c] - Mean[a] + Mean[-b] - Mean[-c] //. {
    Mean[Plus[a_, addends__]] :> Mean[a] + Mean[Plus[addends]],
    Mean[-a_] :> -Mean[a]
    }
```

yields 0.